# What does the phrase 'a high diversion shot' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Context: Cops are trying to get a view on an offender, there is a sniper out there trying to see the offender that is inside the high rise building.

> A: Hailey (the sniper), I need you to get set for *a high diversion shot at the ceiling*.
> No joy, repeat, no joy, on my order.
>
> B: Copy.

Sources: [Feelings Chapter 13, a Chicago PD fanfic | FanFiction](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/13178952/13/Feelings) 
     [Chicago P.D. S7E4 Script](https://transcripts.thedealr.net/script.php/chicago-pd-2014-BljU/s7/e4)

What does *A* mean by **"a high diversion shot at the ceiling"**?

Comment: Note that this is technical jargon and the question may be better directed to a group with the relevant technical specialists (possibly a law enforcement group).

Comment: It's just two adjectives.  If I said "a big red ball" it simply means a ball that is both big and red.  That's all. There's no special meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It probably means for the person to shoot the ceiling to create a diversion into making the offender move and make it easier for the sniper to spot. *Or* the sniper shoots the ceiling to distract the offender and the other person rushes in.

This makes use of the idea that one is tempted or even "forced" to move to trace where the bullet came from and who shoot it, forgetting the fact that there are potentially other shooters around, in this case the sniper.

Comment: This is plausible but it might instead be intended as an actual *diversion* while the sniper moves position themselves; it's a bit hard to say from the brevity of the context but the use of the word *diversion* rather than something nearer to *flushing* suggests its purpose might not be to get the offender to move at all, but to fail to notice something else (the point of a diversion is to divert attention)

Comment: I recognize the scene, and indeed, what happens is that Hailey shoots at the ceiling, the offender looks up, and someone (I believe Jake?) busts in the room and saves the day.

Answer (score 7):

The term ‘diversion shot’ refers to a shot that intentionally misses the intended target with the specific purpose of distracting or startling them. ‘high’ likely refers in context to the angle of the shot, which is supported by the reference to the ceiling.

The general idea is that most people other than highly experienced trained soldiers will end up focusing on the person who fired the diversion shot and neglect the possibility of other shooters or observers (most people will also move almost immediately in a situation like this as well, which is probably what the main goal was in context).